# How to remove key from poco json while iterating it?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

How do I remove key from a Poco json while iterating it? Like:

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr poco_json;
for (auto& objs : *poco_json)
{
     // do something
     if (objs.first == "specific key")
         poco_json->remove(key);     
}
```

or

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr poco_json;
for(auto it = poco_json->begin();it != poco_json->end();)
{
    // do something
    if (it->first == "specific key")
        it = poco_json->remove(it->first);//error : poco didn't have something like this
    else
        ++it;
}
```

the problem is after remove a key from the json, it will invalidate the iterators. I know that in std::map, erase return the valid iterator for next iteration, but I cant find something similar for Poco json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map::erase` returns iterator to next item since C++11, before c++11 you erase items in this way:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
    if (it->first == someKey)
      m.erase(it++); // use post-increment,pass copy of iterator, advance it
    else 
      ++it;
  }
```

and you can do it in similar way while erasing key from `Poco::JSON::Object`. Where did you read that `remove` invalidates iterators?

Some snippet code from source:

```
class JSON_API Object {
    typedef std::map<std::string, Dynamic::Var> ValueMap; // <--- map
    //...
    Iterator begin();
        /// Returns begin iterator for values.
    Iterator end();
        /// Returns end iterator for values.
    void remove(const std::string& key);
        /// Removes the property with the given key.

    ValueMap          _values; // <---

};

inline Object::Iterator Object::begin()
{
    return _values.begin();
}
inline Object::Iterator Object::end()
{
    return _values.end();
}

inline void Object::remove(const std::string& key)
{
    _values.erase(key); // <--- erase is called on map, so iteratos are not invalidated
    if (_preserveInsOrder)
    {
        KeyList::iterator it = _keys.begin();
        KeyList::iterator end = _keys.end();
        for (; it != end; ++it)
        {
            if (key == (*it)->first)
            {
                _keys.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    _modified = true;
}
```

You could rewrite your loop into:

```
for(auto it = poco_json->begin();it != poco_json->end();)
{
    // do something
    if (it->first == "specific key")
    {
        auto copyIt = it++;
        poco_json->remove(copyIt->first);
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

**EDIT**
Why your code doesn't work on range-for loop:

```
for (auto& objs : *poco_json)
{
     // do something
     if (objs.first == "specific key")
         poco_json->remove(key);     
}
```

it is translated into

```
for (auto it = poco_json->begin(); it != poco_json->end(); ++it)
{
     // do something
     if (it->first == "specific key")
         poco_json->remove(it->first);     
    // remove is called, it is erased from inner map
    // ++it is called on iterator which was invalidated, 
    // code crashes
}
```

Comment: @nader so you should provide mvc example, your code based on range-for loop cannot work due to the mechanism how this loop works - iterator is incremented after it was erased, and the second code cannot be compiled.

Comment: i add comment in second code that Poco didn't have a similar mechanism like std map erase. and it's just a example. i search for mechanism like std mape erase for removing but i can't find in Poco

Comment: @nader I edited my answer. You have info why code crashes when range-for loop is ised.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify this code in Poco:

```
inline Iterator Object::remove(const std::string& key)
{
    auto ret_it = _values.erase(key);
    if (_preserveInsOrder)
    {
        KeyList::iterator it = _keys.begin();
        KeyList::iterator end = _keys.end();
        for (; it != end; ++it)
        {
            if (key == (*it)->first)
            {
                _keys.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    _modified = true;

  return ret_it;
}
```

Comment: I can't modify it. it is constraint for me.